# Precompile blue Message. Could not find (Class) OneClickEditDataGridView. Not an error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have OneClickEditDataGridView class in my project which overrides some of normal data-grid functions. See [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8004651f-80a4-4b36-bb56-1518aea66b73/single-clicking-for-textbox-combobox-and-numericupdown-datagridview-columns).

The program compiles and runs as expected however there are 2 blue messages in the VS 2013 Error list.

> Could not find type 'myprogramname.OneClickEdit+OneClickEditDataGridView'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.        0    0
>
> The variable 'DataGridView5' is either undeclared or was never assigned.    mypathtofiles\aFormName.Designer.vb    799    0

The class has been place into the program by adding a new class to the project. I can see it in the solution tree and my program has intellisence it. In order to use it I had to change the designer reference to grid5 from

```
Me.DataGridView5 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
Me.DataGridView5 = New myprogramename.OneClickEdit.OneClickEditDataGridView()
```

as per the instructions from the creator of the class. What can I do to remove these messages, obviously somewhere there is something that needs to be declared?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but when I closed and restarted VS the problem dissipated, but came back, looks like when I had to edit the designer of the form that contains the data grid. Again it went away and did not come back after restarting VS. Still would not give it up for quids. One click edit SHOULD be at least an option directly from the control.